# How to find the two indexes from a list whos values are closest to zero

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working on a piece for my GA (fitness calculation actually) and I need to get the indexes of two values from a list whos values are closest to zero. I have been looking for about an hour all over the internet and though it seems I have become extremely close, and it looks like it should work, testing with print statements show that my code isnt working..

My process right now is:

1. Find the closest index and store it
2. Delete it from original array
3. Find the new closest

this is the code in question:

```
closest = min(range(len(fitness_levels)), key=lambda i: abs(fitness_levels[i]-0))
fitness_levels.pop(closest)
second_closest = min(range(len(fitness_levels)), key=lambda i: abs(fitness_levels[i]-0))
```

when `fitness_levels = [-20, 23, -55, 11, 10, -18, -48, 16, -60, 20, 22, 16, 21, 66, 10, 46, -42]` granted those numbers are generated completely at random.

Like I said, when i do some checking with print statements i find this method doensnt work in multiple ways, at one point i even ended up with the same index different values. Does anyone have a better workable way to do this? - python 2.7.x

Side note- i come from a php background, still warming up to python, so some syntax could be wrong...

Comment: What is the purpose of `fitness_levels[i]-0`?

Comment: When you do `pop()`, all the indices after the pop shift down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While sorting with an `abs` key would work, that's an nlogn solution. Here's a linear solution

```
fitness_levels = [-20, 23, -55, 11, 10, -18, -48, 16, -60, 20, 22, 16, 21, 66, 10, 46, -42]
a,b = sorted(fitness_levels[:2], key=abs) # setting defaults. a<=b
ia, ib = 0,1 # indices
for i,val in enumerate(fitness_levels[2:]): # use itertools.islice for large lists (for constant space)
  if abs(val) < abs(a):
    b,a = a,val
    ib, ia = ia, i
  elif abs(val) < abs(b):
    b = val
    ib = i
```

Comment: This would leave me with a and b as the indexes correct? or am i missing something

Comment: This would leave you with `a` and `b` as the actual values. `ia` and `ib` contain the first-encounter indices of these values (the first index at which these values were encountered; this allows for duplicate fitness values in your list, which GAs usually have)

Comment: This is perfect thanks! One step closer to finishing my neural net, thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
>>> lis = [-20, 23, -55, 11, 10, -18, -48, 16, -60, 20, 22, 16, 21, 66, 10, 46, -42]
for i,x in enumerate(sorted(enumerate(lis), key=lambda x:abs(0 - x[1]))[:2]):
    x = list(x)
    x[0] -= i    #reduce index as an item was removed from the list
    ind, val = x
    print "{}->{}".format(ind, val)
...     
4->10
13->10
```

If you don't want index to be decreased then simply this is enough:

```
>>> sorted(enumerate(lis), key=lambda x:abs(0-x[1]))[:2]
[(4, 10), (14, 10)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for:

```
fitness_levels = [-20, 23, -55, 11, 10, -18, -48, 16, -60, 20, 22, 16, 21, 66, 10, 46, -42]

import heapq
closest2 = heapq.nsmallest(2, ((abs(val), idx) for idx, val in enumerate(fitness_levels)))
# [(10, 4), (10, 14)]
indices = [el[1] for el in closest2]
# [4, 14]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
>>> from numpy import argsort,abs
>>> fitness_levels = [-20,23,-55,11,10,-18,-48,16,-60,20,22,16,21,66,10,46,-42]
>>> i,j = argsort(abs(fitness_levels))[:2]
>>> print (i,fitness_levels[i]),(j,fitness_levels[j])
>>> (14 10) (4 10)
```